# add Footer to custom lsitview

Tags: android, footer, listadapter

How to  add a Footer to a **listView with Adapter** ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

I've try this :

```
 public class message extends ListActivity {
       List<SMSData2> smsList2 = new ArrayList<SMSData2>();
        private Context context = null;
        private ListView list = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            //code to set adapter to populate 
for (int i=0;; i < 10; i++) {
                SMSData2 sms2 = new 
                sms2.setBody(c.getString("some text");
                smsList2.add(sms2);
                setListAdapter(new ListAdapter2(this, smsList2));
                        }
              View footerView =              ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
            list.addFooterView(footerView);
        }


    }
```

but it returns `java.lang.NullPointerException` !

**possible issues :**

bug with the inflater !

Bug with the context !

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest solutin is to define a linear layout that has 2 items first is your list view and the second is the footer.

if however you still insist on using a footer by the footer method you do so from activity code:

```
//after code to set adapter to populate list
        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: thanks but i'd like to use a list adpater ? Could we still use the same method ?

Comment: @LaurentPrat how is that preventing you from doing so? the adapter is for the list items, a footer is something meant to be like a static item like an action button or a text, if you want a footer that used to sum the info from the list then still the adapter is  based on an array or cursor right? set the adapter to the list, and make another set of calculations for the footer and present it to the footer item. at anyhow i added the answer to show use of footer

Answer (score 1):

Call the method

```
addFooterView (View v)
```

and pass the view you want to add to the listview.
The listview is already having this method.
Have a look on the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).